# Make Binary Columns in groups - using R

Tags: r

I have binary cols and id like to group by pairs
HAVE

```
A B C 
1 0 0 
0 1 1 
0 1 1 
1 1 0
```

WANT

```
A B C group 
1 0 1   AC 
0 1 1   BC
0 1 1   BC
1 1 0   AB
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apply` in base R and paste the column names where the value in the row is 1.

```
cols <- names(df)
df$group <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste0(cols[x == 1], collapse = ''))
df

#  A B C group
#1 1 0 1    AC
#2 0 1 1    BC
#3 0 1 1    BC
#4 1 1 0    AB
```

With `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(group = paste0(cols[c_across() == 1], collapse = '')) %>%
  ungroup
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), B = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    C = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Operations done on rows can be more efficient with `dapply` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
df$group <- dapply(df, FUN = function(x) 
     paste(names(df)[as.logical(x)], collapse=""), MARGIN = 1)
df$group
#[1] "AC" "BC" "BC" "AB"
```

---

Or another option is `unite` after changing the elements to the column names

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~case_when(as.logical(.) ~ 
      cur_column(), TRUE ~ ''))) %>% 
  unite(group, !!! names(.), sep="") %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)
#  A B C group
#1 1 0 1    AC
#2 0 1 1    BC
#3 0 1 1    BC
#4 1 1 0    AB
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), B = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    C = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option

```
df$group <- sapply(Map(subset, list(names(df)), as.data.frame(t(df) > 0)), paste0, collapse = "")
```

giving

```
> df
  A B C group
1 1 0 1    AC
2 0 1 1    BC
3 0 1 1    BC
4 1 1 0    AB
```